# Get a list of Worksheets using Zend Gdata API for PHP

Tags: php, zend-gdata

I want to list all the worksheets with the name of the sheet and the "worksheetid" which is used in the API to reference the sheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a script you can use to output all of the worksheets and their ids for a particular spreadsheet. It takes a URL query string of 'name' which is the name of the spreadsheet whose worksheets you want the ids of (e.g. name-of-file.php?name=myspreadsheet)

```
<?php
    set_include_path($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/library/");

    require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
    $autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoloader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

/**
 * Username, password and the name of the spreadsheet we would like to use
 * Note that the spreadsheet is case sensitive and white space sensitive
 */

    $user = "your-gmail-account-name-at-gmail-dot-com";
    $pass = "your-gmail-account-password";
    if($_POST['name'])
    {
        $spreadsheetToFind = $_POST['name'];
    }
    elseif($_GET['name'])
    {
        $spreadsheetToFind = $_GET['name'];
    }

/**
 * Establish a connection to our spreadsheets and get a complete list of them
 */

    $service            = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
    $client             = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
    $spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
    $feed               = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();

/**
 * We loop through all of the spreadsheets until we have found the one
 * declared earlier. The id of the spreadsheet is then extracted using
 * basename and we store the id for use in our next query, to
 * obtain all of the worksheets in the spreadsheet
 */

    foreach($feed->entries as $entry)
    {               
        $spreadsheetTitle = $entry->title->text;

        if($spreadsheetTitle == $spreadsheetToFind)
        {
            $spreadsheetURL = $entry->id;
        }
    }

    $spreadsheetKey = basename($spreadsheetURL);

    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_DocumentQuery();
    $query->setSpreadsheetKey($spreadsheetKey);
    $feed = $spreadsheetService->getWorksheetFeed($query); // now that we have the desired spreadsheet, we need the worksheets

/**
 * Loop through all of our worksheets and echo
 * its name as well as its id
 */

    echo("<table><tr><td><strong>Spreadsheet Name:</strong></td><td>" . $spreadsheetToFind . "</td></tr><tr><td><strong>Spreadsheet ID:</strong></td><td>" . $spreadsheetKey . "</td></tr>");

    foreach($feed->entries as $entry)
    {
        echo("<tr><td><strong>".$entry->title->text . ": </strong></td><td>".basename($entry->id)."</td></tr>");

    }

    echo("</table>");
?>
```

Note that this script depends on the Zend library being at your document root in a folder named 'library'.

Comment: WOW! I can't believe anyone is still looking at this question. It's funny because I gave up and told people to open some test page I made that showed the urls's of the spreadsheets and Ctrl-F for the name of the sheet they made and once you find it look backwards to a slash and then take the next three letters and that is the worksheet id. I'll look at this today though!

Comment: Let me know if you need any clarification on the script. I've been doing a lot with the Google Docs API lately and I use this to get my IDs. Should be simpler than looking through the text for slashes and the three letter ID :p